# Accessing Multiple Tables Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Hi I have looked at numerous answers on this similar to my question but none have more than one WHERE. 
I am trying to see if there is something in my database across multiple tables.

The code I have is as follows:

```
<?php 


$sql = "SELECT id FROM groom, lroom, try WHERE groom.person = $a AND lroom.person = $a AND try.person = $a";

        $result = $conn -> query ($sql);


     if($result -> num_rows >0){
 //DO SOMETHING }else{//Dont do anything}   
    ?>
```

SAMPLE DATABASE

```
groom
id   room   person
1     4       1 

lroom
id   room   person
6     8       1 

try
id   court   person
8    2       1 


$a = 1;
```

RESULT should be 1,6,8
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: look into join on

Comment: update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected  result .. please

Comment: Your statement is that you want to identify something that exists in all tables.  if that's the case then you want to do something similar to what you've done, but since all 3 tables have a column ID, you need to either select all three or just one that is prefixed.  You could use union, but you won't get one row you'll get up to 3 rows as a response and it will return IDs for any tables.  If the condition is that you want to verify entities that exist in all 3 tables, the union becomes problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you need  the same values form the 3 tables you could use union

```
 select id 
 from groom
 where groom.person = $a
 union 
 select id 
 from lroom
 where lroom.person = $a
 union 
 select id 
 from try
 where try.person = $a
```

you need  just the value that match for all the 3 tables

```
  SELECT id 
  FROM groom
  inner join on groom.person  = lroom.person 
  inner join try on groom.person = try.person 
  where groom.person= $a";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but from what it looks like, you need a statement like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT groom.id AS groomid, lroom.id AS lroomid, try.id AS tryid FROM groom, lroom, try WHERE groom.person = ".$a." AND lroom.person = ".$a". AND try.person = ".$a;
```

If `$a` not an integer or boolean value, then add quotation marks in your SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT groom.id AS groomid, lroom.id AS lroomid, try.id AS tryid FROM groom, lroom, try WHERE groom.person = '".$a."' AND lroom.person = '".$a"'. AND try.person = '".$a."'";
```